# Inner class's property having outer class's generic type

Tags: java, inner-classes

I have a class **Item** which will be used as generic type in the following class:

```java
abstract class AbstractClass<I extends Item, V extends AbstractClass.Inner> {
    abstract class Inner {
        I item;
    }
}
```

Then I subclass **AbstractClass** also its **Inner** with **Page** extending **Item** mentionned above:

```java
class ImpClass extends AbstractClass<Page, ImpClass.Inner> {
    class Inner extends AbstractClass.Inner {
        void method(){
             // Setup item
             // Printout class of item, which is Page
             item.callMethodOfPage(); // won't compile without conversion to Page
        }
    }
}
```

Theorically, *item* in **ImpClass.Inner** should be **Page** and has the method only in **Page**. Is it because i'm misssing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AbstractClass.Inner` is a raw type. You need to parameterize `AbstractClass`:

```
abstract class AbstractClass<I extends Item, V extends AbstractClass<I, V>.Inner> {
    abstract class Inner {
        I item;
    }
}

class ImpClass extends AbstractClass<Page, ImpClass.Inner> {
    abstract class Inner extends AbstractClass<Page, Inner>.Inner {
        void method(){
             // Setup item
             // Printout class of item, which is Page
             item.callMethodOfPage(); // compiles
        }
    }
}
```